# How to execute forEach controller Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I'm calling an API(`HTTP Request`) from that I am extracting ids(`JSON JMESPath Extractor`). Using those Ids I want to again hit APIs (`HTTP Request`).

I've added Debug Sampler there I got

```
ids=2cf341f2-1dda-4fe6-b663-2a509f5d485e

ids_matchNr=136
```

But how to hit using `HTTP Request` this all 136 ids?

Answer (score 0):

[image: For Each]

Here `HTTP Request` within forEach controller will take variable as ${ids} and execute for all ids.

Comment: In my case, ForEach Controller is not executing

Answer (score 0):

You will be only able to use ForEach Controller if you have **consecutive** [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) like:

```
ids_1=some id
ids_2=some_other_id
```

[image]

So double check that your variables are matching this pattern using [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener combination

Example approach: [Using Regular Expressions in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-regular-expressions-jmeter)